# PHP array_keys - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have two arrays:

$fieldNames:

```
array(
[0] => array(
    ['fieldName'] =>'id'
    ['fieldType'] => 'int(11)'
    )
[1] =>
    ['fieldName'] =>'adminID'
    ['fieldType'] =>'int(11)'
    )
[2] =>array(
    ['fieldName'] =>'schoolID'
    ['fieldType'] =>'int(11)'
    )
[3] => array(
    ['fieldName'] =>'lessonPlanName'
    ['fieldType'] =>'varchar(255)'
    )
[4] =>array(
    ['fieldName'] =>'lessonPlanAssignmentDate'
    ['fieldType'] =>'varchar(255)'
    )
[5] =>array(
   ['fieldName'] =>'lessonPlanDueDate'
   ['fieldType'] =>'varchar(255)'
   )
[6] =>array(
   ['fieldName'] =>'lessonPlanTopics'
   ['fieldType'] =>'varchar(255)'
   )
[7] =>array(
   ['fieldName'] =>'lessonPlanDescription'
   ['fieldType'] =>'text'
   )
[8] =>array(
   ['fieldName'] =>'lessonPlanNotes'
   ['fieldType'] =>'text'
   )
)
```

$formElementPairs:

```
array(
   ['lessonPlanName'] =>'Test'
   ['lessonPlanAssignedDate'] =>'05/11/2011'
   ['lessonPlanDueDate'] =>'05/11/2011'
   ['lessonPlanTopics'] => 1
   ['lessonPlanDescription'] =>'test'
```

)

I'm trying to check to see if array 2 is missing any of the 'fieldName' keys from array 1 and then add them to array 2 with null entries. The following code works in that I am getting the "fieldName" values from the first array (id, adminId, schoolId, etc.) but when I go to check them against the second array using array_keys, my resulting array always has a count of 0. Should also mention I am stuck using PHP4 on this project.

```
//merge arrays
for($fn=0; $fn<count($fieldNames); $fn++) { 
    $thisFieldName = $fieldNames[$fn]['fieldName'];
    $fieldCheckArray = array_keys($formElementPairs, $thisFieldName);
    //$firephp->fb(count($fieldCheckArray));
}
```

Am I misunderstanding array_keys and/or is there a more elegant way to do this in PHP4?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `array_key_exists` to check if array 2 is missing anything:
array_key_exists

```
$missing = array();
for($fn=0; $fn<count($fieldNames); $fn++) { 
    $thisFieldName = $fieldNames[$fn]['fieldName'];
    if(!array_key_exists($thisFieldName, $formElementPairs)) {
        $missing[] = $thisFieldName;
    }
}
//do something with $missing
```

Comment: I'll try that, but any idea why array_keys wouldn't work the way I am using it?

Comment: @pruitigoe `array_keys` returns a array of the keys found for the **value** passed. See the [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `array_keys` is attempting to match the *values* and not the *keys* of `$formElementPairs`.

Comment: Look at this example (2nd one)  at w3schools:<br><?php
$a=array("a"=>"Horse","b"=>"Cat","c"=>"Dog");
print_r(array_keys($a,"Dog"));
?> <br>http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_keys.asp

Comment: Look at this example (2nd one)  at w3schools:`<?php
$a=array("a"=>"Horse","b"=>"Cat","c"=>"Dog");
print_r(array_keys($a,"Dog"));
?>`The result will be Array ( [0] => c)  Isn't that getting a match result by checking the values of a key?                 [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_keys.asp)